# Java loop confusion requiring assistance

Tags: java

So i need help, i am trying to input a Y/N program but it is not accepting a big 'Y' or 'N'. Also another thing that i am trying to do is after pressing 'Y'/'y' i am trying to get the program to loop back to the code written above. Example a program that displays '123' and do i need to continue? Y/N, if entered yes it goes back up to restart the program from scratch. Please help me.

```
System.out.println("continue? Yes or no ");

       char check = s.next().charAt(0);

while (check != 'y' && response != 'n')// corrected this part, however need help with restarting the loop back to the first line of code in a loop {

  System.out.println("\nInvalid response. Try again.");
  check = s.next().charAt(0);

} if ((check == 'n') || (check == 'N')) {

    // I tried (check == 'n' || check == 'N') 
    System.out.println("Program terminated goodbye.");
    System.exit(0);

} else if (check == 'y') {
//need help with restarting the loop back to the first line of code in a loop 
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: I dont know where i went wrong hence the question.

Comment: _You_ wrote your code to not accept any uppercase input, so why do you expect it to accept it anyway?

Comment: Omg you are right... How silly of me.. I corrected that part. Do you have any idea how to continue the program back to the top after pressing y?

Comment: There are already answered questions for that part. Search on Stackoverflow and you'll find them.

Comment: I tried using break; or continue; after pressing 'y' area however it keeps saying break/switch outside loop

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
    char check;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do
    {
        //your piece of code in here e.g.
        System.out.println("Printed 123");
        System.out.println("Do you wish to continue?[Y/y] or [N/n]");
        choice = scanner.next().charAt(0);

    }while (check =='Y' || check == 'y');

    System.out.println("Program terminated goodbye.");
```

A `do-while` loop runs at least once before the condition is checked and so when a user enters either Y or y, then the condition will be true, meaning that they wish for the loop to run again. If the user enters any other value, then the condition will become false since choice is neither Y nor y and the loop will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check without case-sensitive, you should convert the char to a `String`, then do `s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2);`

So

```
while(true) {
    System.out.println("Continue? [Y/N]");
    char check_char = s.next().charAt(0);
    String check = Character.toString(check_char);

    while(check.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        System.out.println("\nInvalid response. Try again.");
        check = s.next().charAt(0);
    }

    if (check.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        System.out.println("Program terminated goodbye.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

For returning to the first line, I used a while loop that loops forever.

To the end if it is *n* then exits, otherwise it returns back to the first line of the loop.

Comment: `char` and `String` are very different. `char` is a primitive, it does **not** have any method. (actually it is an integral type like `int` and for sure is compared with `==`)

Comment: My bad, I thought it was a String. Look at the edit

Answer (score 0):

Use String.equals() to compare the value of strings, == compares the strings in memory.

Comment: as I already commented in Simone's answer, the code is comparing `char` not `String`, and `char` is compared with `==` since it is a primitive (in Java)